# For Loop Container in SSIS(Using Nested for loop)

Tags: for-loop, ssis

I need to load data for four financial years every day(Around 60 Million Rows). In order to achieve that I created a for loop container which is for Financial year(comparing two variables StartYear and CurrentFinancialyear). In this for container I'm using one more for loop container(This loop is for comparing each month data in that financial year).

Attached properties for Outer and Inner Loop

In the **outer For loop** the properties are FYStart=2016 and CurrentFY=2020(Comparing year to year) and in **inner loop** the properties are FYStartPeriod=1 and FYEndPeriod=12(I'm comparing month to month in inner loop)

**The Problem is Outer loop stops after the first iteration and not comparing for other years.**

[image: Package Creation]
[OuterLoop Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFa3v.png)
[InnerLoop Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54Vu.png)

Comment: Please show us how the outer ForLoop container is configured along with the initialization values for the referenced variables. Please click the "edit" link in the question instead of attempting to reply in comments

Comment: Not clear what your asking/need help with, you have some code there, but what is not working specifically/what do you need help with? (or if its just me I apologize)

Comment: Hi Brad, Is the question clear or do you require more information regarding this?